Json::Serializable don't use default value from proc
I'm trying to provide a default value for a struct attribute that is generated instead.
However when deserializing, the value is still nill.
playground:
require "json"

struct A
  include JSON::Serializable

  property first_seen : Time { Time.utc }
  property count : Int64 = 1
  def initialize(@first_seen : Time , count)
    @count = count.to_i64
  end
end

a = A.from_json("{}")

pp a
# A(@count=1, @first_seen=nil)
puts typeof(a.first_seen) 
# Time
puts  A.from_json("{}").to_json
# {"count":1}

I suppose this happens, because the default value is unknown at compile time.
I have a work around by using after_initialize.
I would expect either the serialization to use the default value or the deserialization to execute the proc to get the default value.
Is there another way than using after_initialize ?

Isn't from_json("{}") kinda odd since it should have a first_seen set already?

Using a block to initialize first_seen was a bad idea.
It's possible to write directly: property first_seen : Time = Time.utc:
require "json"

struct A
  include JSON::Serializable

  property first_seen : Time = Time.utc
  property count : Int64 = 1
  def initialize(@first_seen : Time , count)
    @count = count.to_i64
  end
end

From the doc:

If a block is given to the macro, a property is generated with a variable that is lazily initialized with the block's contents

